# How to save properties of a listview in a list?

Tags: flutter

Okay I have a feature to implement in my flutter app. I have a list of video URL from my database on a server that shows up in a listview and plays the video when clicked, but I want to save details of the video like it's id, URL and name in a list so I can use it to make a listview of recently played videos.

I don't know how to go about this, but what I Have in mind is, when a video is clicked I somehow save those details I need to implement what I want, I also want it to be stored so the user can see it every time. I need help with this, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.
What you need to do is to do is create a database and have a table for the recent viewed list. So when a user clicks on the video, the details are saved into that table and they can be retrieved later on.
Flutter has several ways for you to implement a database.

1. You can use SQFLite, the flutter implementation of SQLITE
2. You can also use [MOOR](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/) or [HIVE](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/).

You can check out this cookbook for how to use [SQFlite](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'll go-ahead to try it out. I'll give an update on how it goes.

Comment: I used SQFLite and it works just fine, the way I want. Thanks @Dean

Comment: Glad I could help @henrymaykhid